# Create intermediate repeated string, and pass to UDF in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

My ultimate goal is to pass a repeated string field into a BigQuery UDF, to create a form of a varargs UDF.

Is there a nicer way than:

`SELECT output from myUDF(SELECT split(concat(field1, ':', field2, ...), ':') ...)`

For example, it would be great to be able to have a `REPEATED` built-in constructor:

`SELECT output from myUDF(SELECT REPEATED(field1, field2) as fields ...)`

Comment: I think you should just move this logic inside UDF

Comment: fair enough - but still, the call to CONCAT would remain, and then it's easy to forget the delimiter.

Comment: no CONCAT, you should just do - SELECT output FROM myUDF(SELECT field1, field2 ...). All the logic go to UDF. Unless you first need to do aggregations :)  Specific example would help to nail this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you - we've been thinking about whether or not varargs-style support would be useful when we launch scalar functions.  It's helpful to hear that users would find such a feature compelling as we work on planning the feature.

The workaround you posted is probably your best option at this time.

Comment: Thanks - in fact the motivation for this varargs-style UDF is driven by the lack of scalar functions: I want to apply the same function to multiple common fields from various tables (I'll use the example of validating addresses).  Rather than write a UDF per input schema, I'd rather construct a "lookup" subquery that applies to all address fields at once, and provides the "corrected" output.  Still, it would be useful to have varargs scalars, in the sense that we can then validate multiple addresses (e.g. the address per transaction) along a different dimension (e.g. by customer).